# I can't compile, but others can?

Tags: errors, compiling, overleaf

I'm working on a project, where I can't compile, but two other people sitting next to me can - even though its the exact same document?

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: ...not without some example files and/or further information on what machine you use and what machines the two other people use.

Comment: We're all using windows. If my friend copies the file, and shares it with me i can compile. Its still the exact same file.
I dont really know how to share the sample file, the PDF is 100 pages, so its a lot of code and subfiles.

Comment: Do you use the same version of LateX? Same texlive/MikTeX-Versions installed on all machines?

Comment: It can be everything. Please read your message thinking that you are at your computer, doing a completely different thing, knowing nothing about the problem, and you have to guess everything...

Comment: Different package versions are the most common cause of this. But it could also be that the same error persists on both machines, but that the editor on the machines where things produce output are set up to scroll past error messages (Overleaf for example does that https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/35864). What kind of error do you get?

Comment: We're all using overleaf.
Yes it can be everything, thats why i was thinking that other people had the same problem. We can rule out a lot of things, just by the simple fact that others can compile the exact same document while i cant.

Comment: We can't help you unless you give us some more information. Do error messages appear on your machine? Which one?

Comment: Im having a bunch of errors, but its mainly because were using Æ Ø Å. I have the same errors as they have.

Comment: So it is not really running on their machines either? Let me put it this way: What error messages appear on your machines that do NOT appear on theirs?

Comment: I am getting some errors on output.lot line 16 that they dont have?

Comment: when asking about an error always show the exact error from the log file in a code  section in your question so line endings are preserved.

Comment: Check which version of TeX Live your instance of the project is using. https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version In principle that is the only thing that can differ between you and your colleagues if you are sharing exactly the same project.

Comment: your overleaf link shows 65!!! errors, just start with the first and fix them one by one, later errors are often spurious an dwill go if ypu fix earlier ones, but the PDF output is not usable at all if theer is any error.

Comment: I will definitely fix all errors.
But i fixed it, by clearing the cache.
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: In `Udfligning.tex`  lin 139 you need to replace whatever looks like `å` with actual å, it seems to have been typed using the unicode circle accent + a

Comment: Please note that you are making a `lot` of mistakes in this document, both mistakes that gives errors but also general typographical mistakes.

Comment: Ive been wondering about that error too, but now i will clean up the document. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anything specific, daleif?

Comment: Not only are you using the combining ring accent U+030A you are using it _before_ the a not after, so it would apply to th epreceding g (if it worked at all) not to the a.

Comment: never use `\end{equation} \\`  for example. (you should probably remove all `\\ ` that are not in tables.

Comment: Thanks david, will look into it.

Comment: a heck of a lot: using ``\\`` in the text is always wrong, blank lines above math (you cannot see it because you removed the paragraph indentation, are you at AAU-DK?), you cannot use æøå in math mode. The `siunitx` package ought to be used for units.

Comment: never use `\\ ` at end of a paragraph like `udnyttet. \\ `  you must get warning about badnes 10000 from that (10000 is the _maximum_ level of badness Tex assigns to its output)

Comment: less important, but since you asked, don't use `$$` in latex (use `\[...\]`)

Comment: The thing is, we've been trying to let latex change lines. if just do it by typing enter it doesnt, it will continue text on the same line. Thats why we've been using \\. Yes i am from AAU. Im writing this with a guy who has dyslexia, so typos will be fixed before handing it in.

Comment: Thanks David, did not know about that. What is the difference?

Comment: size commands  do not take an argument so don't do ` \huge{\bfseries Dim`   or same with `\large` etc, as the size will apply to all of the following text not just the text in the brace group, try `\huge{abc} xyz`   xyz will be huge.

Comment: What is the other option? that is why we've been using \large{text}\\ 
To break the text, seems to work.

Comment: `$$` is not  supported syntax at all in latex it is tex primitive syntax that sometimes works.= but no standard latex documentation even mentions it.

Comment: the syntax for large would be `{\large text\par}`

Comment: You gues from AAU are known to remove paragraph indentation without any reason to. There is a reason it is there so don't remove it.

Comment: S2 line 22 `\alpha` needs `$...$`, line 35 `\epsilon` same

Comment: S4 line 54 `\alfa` needs to be `\alpha`. As you can see never just ignore errors in Overleaf just because it generates a PDF does not mean it is ok

Comment: S6 line 70 use `F_{\textrm{skrå}}` same on line 95 and 110 and 118

Comment: After those I can get it to compile without errors. Then there is all the bad habits that David also mentions. I would add learning to properly use floats instead of `[H]` all the time. You should also load hyperref a lot later. Generally use `\textrm{}` for all the named indices that are in Danish.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because potentially not helpful for future readers.